# Create a new field and update a content type (and all implementations)

Tags: sharepoint

I'm doing some work on an existing SharePoint site and part of what I need to do is create a new field on an existing content type.

I'm going to be deploying changes via a feature so I'm debating whether I use CAML to generate the field and then programmatically add it to the existing content type, or whether I can just do it all via the feature receiver.

What would be the best/ cleanest (and most reusable) solution for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to do it in the feature receiver, get a reference to the SPContentType, add the field as XML (SPContentType.Fields.AddFieldAsXml) and then [update pushing the changes to child content types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442695.aspx)

It is really tricky to modify content types on a site that already exists. My preferred method involves having a solution for all the content types and re-deploying that solution when changes are made.

Comment: I'm doing what the linked article stated but I keep getting "Collection cannot be modified" when doing the contentType.Update(true). Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, could be one of the fields that are being modified is a publishing field or otherwise kicks up a fuss when it is altered.
Try making the changes one at a time and see which one dies.

Comment: I got the "Collection cannot be modified" exception as well, until I figured out that I had gotten the content type reference from the `AvailableContentTypes` collection of the site. When I modified my code to use the `ContentTypes` collection instead, the exception was not thrown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go on the assumption that by *field* you mean a new **Site Column**.  In this case I would do it all in the code behind.  The amount of code that you need to write   to create a site column is rather minimal.  You can also attempt to remove the Site Column from any Content Types that are using it if you wish, but this is a task that is quite more involved.

From a reuse perspective if you set-up properties in the [feature.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475601.aspx) file you can use those to configure things such as the column name, column type, target content type, etc. and then have a class that can be re-used in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537575.aspx, in particular the `< AddContentTypeField>` tag?  That would be a declarative way to do this.